# Port 3306 not opened in MemSQL community edition install

Tags: singlestore

I'm not able to connect with:
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --prompt="memsql> "
it yields:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

When I run nmap localhost, port 3306 appears to not be open. When I google for a solution the suggestions offered do not yield any results. What do i need to do to get port 3306 open?

Edit. From the log:
00000104 2015-05-21 02:01:46 FATAL: This machine does not have enough CPU cores to run MemSQL. The minimum required number is 4, and this machine has 2 cores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that memsqld is not running, and therefore not listening on its default port.

You can check the ports that are open with ss:

```
ss -natl
```

You can check to see if memsqld is running with ps:

```
ps -ef | grep memsql
```

The log file should be in /var/lib/memsql/tracelogs/memsql.log. In there may be a clue to what happened on installation.

Also, make sure that the system requirements are met: 
http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/requirements/

Comment: I've updated the original post to include log information. I was running the full version on the exact same cluster for weeks with no issues. Is the 4 cores a new requirement?

Comment: Also, MemSQL ops is showing activity in the dashboard. it shows my aggregators and my leaves and things are jumping around.

Comment: Yes, the minimum was raised to 4 cores with the GA of MemSQL 4. What you are seeing in Ops is likely memsqld processes being started (by ops agent) and stopping again (because of the CPU requirement).

Answer (score 0):

With the default configuration the MySQL client will attempt to connect to a local MySQL server. You can connect to MemSQL with `mysql -uroot -h0` if using the default port of 3306 and have not added a password to the root user.